# Como generar archivo csv a partir de otro

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv

Tengo una aplicación que exporta varios archivos con respuestas en formato .csv (alrededor de 100 archivos).

Lo que necesito hacer esque una vez generado el primer archivo de respuestas poder leer cuántas líneas tiene (un count) y poder generar un segundo csv con este resultado:

Ejemplo:

```
TituloDelProjecto     NumeroDeLineas
ProjectA              350
```

Una vez hecho esto, necesito que al generar el segundo archivo csv. La lectura del count pueda ser agregada (append) a este nuevo segundo archivo.

Ejemplo:

```
TituloDelProjecto     NumeroDeLineas
ProjectA              350
ProjectB              170
```

Cada archivo de respuestas, tiene un encabezado. La idea es poder saltarme este encabezado cada vez que se lea el csv y haga el count en hacia el segundo archivo.

Este es parte de mi codigo el cual genera estos archivos de respuesta:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in d.GetFiles("*.csv")) //
{
    if (!(file.Name.IndexOf("__") >= 0))
    {
        string originalFileName = file.FullName;
        int y = file.Name.IndexOf("_");
        string newFileName = zipFileName + file.Name.Substring(y);

        newFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(outCsvFile) + @"\" + newFileName;
        if (File.Exists(newFileName))
        {
            File.Delete(newFileName);
        }
        File.Move(originalFileName, newFileName);

        files.Add(newFileName);  //newFileName me da el archivo de respuesta                              

    }
}
```

Les agradezco la ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. No veo que problema tienes en la pregunta que has publicado, edita la pregunta para aclarar que problema específico tienes

Comment: Podrías hacerlo fácilmente usando

    File.AppendAllText("date.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString());

Si necesitas nueva linea

    File.AppendAllText("date.txt", 
                   DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

Tendrias que ir leyedo los archivos y los vas insertando en lineas nuevas para que no los  borre los anteriores, creo q es asi. en java es Line.netxLine en c# me suena que era asi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Lo que necesito hacer es que una vez generado el primer archivo de respuestas. Poder leer cuantas líneas tiene (un count)

Es sencillo contar cuántas líneas tiene un archivo de texto, basta con saber cuántos saltos de línea tiene:

```
var lineas = File.ReadAllText(@"archivo").Count(c => c == '\n'));
```

> Necesito que al generar el segundo archivo csv. La lectura del count pueda ser agregada (append) a este nuevo segundo archivo.

Esa es una aproximación incorrecta, no tiene sentido abrir-escribir-cerrar un archivo cada vez, eso es lentísimo. Genera una cadena de caracteres con el resultado y escríbelo una sola vez:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("TituloDelProjecto\tNumeroDeLineas\n");

foreach (FileInfo file in d.GetFiles("*.csv"))
{
    var lineas = File.ReadAllText(@"archivo").Count(c => c == '\n'));
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\n", file.Name, lineas);
}

using (StreamWriter resultado = new StreamWriter("resultado .txt"))
{
    resultado.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: O `File.ReadAllLines(@"archivo").Count()`...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo que pasa que el archivo nunca es unico, es diferente cada vez que se exporta, lo cual requiero tener una linea por cada uno de estos archivos para asi poder tener el count de cada uno de ellos

Comment: @a.morales y una línea tendrás por cada uno de ellos: en el `foreach` de `FileInfo`s vas anexando (`Append`) una línea por archivo, al final de dicho bucle se escribe de una sola vez, todos los archivos analizados.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, al ejecutar veo que el archivo no se borra una vez creado pero los datos adentro del archivo cuando llega a la linea StreamWriter resultado se reinicia y solo toma el ultimo archivo de respuestas. Gracias

Comment: Correcion, como el archivo resultado se crea a cvada vez, este hace que se reinicie y esto pasa al ejecutarse el  StreamWriter

Comment: Ecnontre como hacerlo, agregue esto y funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias!!
using (StreamWriter resultado = new StreamWriter("Result.csv", append:true))

Comment: @a.morales perdona por la respuesta tardía a tus comentarios: si sucede que el archivo se te reinicia no has seguido mi consejo: **NO** debes escribir el archivo de resultados con cada archivo de datos, debes leer todos los datos y escribir el archivo de resultados **una sola vez**, tal y como muestro en el código de ejemplo.